# Ansible regex filters

Tags: regex, ansible, roles

I need to extract some text from a variable in ansible.

```
 - name: Find modules
   shell: find "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ flavor_modules }}/modules.d/" -name "*.yml"
   register: modules_list


 - debug:
     msg: "aca {{ item }}"
   with_items: "{{ modules_list }}"
```

So modules list returns something like this: `/etc/ansible/roles/filebeat/files/something/modules.d/haproxy.yml`
I need to register or create a new variable that looks like this: `haproxy.yml`
I been trying with some regex expressions with no luck.

Comment: I think you just want the [basename filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names).

Comment: Or perhaps with [the fileglob lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html)

Comment: and try to use slurp instead of shell.

Comment: advice: Don't run command `find` in a shell use the dedicated module [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)